# Snowflake not showing Results when seen from the query history

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When the queries are run from a Snowflake stored procedure then the Results tab is not showing the results:

Initially a Javascript based stored procedure is called which contains a try and a catch block to handle the COMMIT or ROLLBACK i.e. COMMIT only if all the commands are completed successfully or ROLLBACK if any of the commands fail. From this try block an SQL based stored procedure is called which contains a bunch of merge + insert + delete commands.

I am looking at one of those insert commands and when seen from Query History the Results section is not showing any results.

The stored procedure is created and triggered manually by the user `TGOUD` which is my Snowflake username.

I need to view the Results to debug sometimes, I can use an insert command and write the required info to another table, but I would like to know the Results are not being shown up?

[image]

Comment: does `SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(<QUERY_ID>))` for that insert show you the results?

Comment: If the same query is run as a standalone query then it is showing the results. If the same query is run from a stored procedure then it is not showing the results. That is the concern.

Comment: Is the SP being run as caller or owner? Who is the caller/owner?

Answer (score 0):

When you write "triggered manually" I'm inferring that you're referring to the `execute task` since the documentation refers to triggering (rather than a classic database trigger):

> EXECUTE TASK
>
> Manually triggers an asynchronous single run of a scheduled task (either a standalone task or the root task in a DAG (directed acyclic graph) of tasks) independent of the schedule defined for the task.

Since it seems that a task is involved, there's a filter that needs to be enabled to view queries run by tasks:

[image]